# Removing JLabels with the "same" name

Tags: java, swing, panel, jlabel

I'm doing a 4 in a row game, and i'm adding the red or green piece as a label, but always the same label, to the panel game. My code is like this (the relevant one)

```
labeljogo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon( bola ));

if(f.getSource()==setaL1 && c1==6 && modoDeJogo==2 || setaPc=="setaL1" && c1==6 && modoDeJogo==3 && jogadorActual==2 || f.getSource()==setaL1 && c1==6  && modoDeJogo==3 && jogadorActual==1 || modoDeJogo==4 && setaPc=="setaL1" && c1==6)
    {
        labeljogo.setBounds(150, 100, 60, 60);
        c1++;
        matrix[1][0]=jogadorActual;
    }
if(f.getSource()==setaL1 && c1==6 && modoDeJogo==2 || setaPc=="setaL1" && c1==6 && modoDeJogo==3 && jogadorActual==2 || f.getSource()==setaL1 && c1==6  && modoDeJogo==3 && jogadorActual==1 || modoDeJogo==4 && setaPc=="setaL1" && c1==6)
    {
        labeljogo.setBounds(150, 100, 60, 60);
        c1++;
        matrix[1][0]=jogadorActual;
    }
```

(...) and it continues until all the 8*8 pieces are in the panel

the image bola changes by changing player.

My doubt is if there is any way of cleaning all this JLabels that all have the same name. Because when I call the

```
 panel.remove(labeljogo);
```

It only removes the last one.

Is there any way of removing this JLabels without affecting the other JLabels?

Comment: Don't use "==" to compare Strings. Use the equals(...) method.

Comment: May be it's better to use html for one label instead of multiple labels for different colors?

Comment: Kind of tricky to use html in Java Swing no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<Main.panel.getComponentCount (); i++)
    if(Main.panel.getComponent(i).getBounds ( ).height==60)
        Main.panel.getComponent(i).setVisible(false);
```

used this method to remove the `JLabel`s by height. It worked fine.